# MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

- My Apex Class

```
public with sharing class WeekendTimeSheetAlerts implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    
    final String weekToSubmit;
    final String query;
    final Date weekMondayDate;
    final Date weekFridayDate;

    public WeekendTimeSheetAlerts()
    {
        Date todayDate = Date.today();
        Date weekStart = todayDate.toStartofWeek();
        
        Integer daysBetween = weekStart.daysBetween(todayDate);
        weekToSubmit = daysBetween > 4 ? 'THIS_WEEK' : 'LAST_WEEK';

        Date weekMonday = weekToSubmit == 'THIS_WEEK' ? weekStart : weekStart.addDays(-7);
        if(((DateTime) weekMonday).format('E') == 'Sun'){
            weekMonday = weekMonday.addDays(1);
        }
        weekMondayDate = weekMonday;
        weekFridayDate = weekMonday.addDays(4);

        query = 'SELECT Id, CreatedById, Start_Date_Time__c FROM Log__c '+
        'WHERE Status__c = \'Submit for Approval\' AND Start_Date_Time__c = '+ weekToSubmit +' ORDER BY CreatedById, Start_Date_Time__c';
        System.debug('query   ' + query);
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
  
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Log__c> scope)
    {
        //Map<Id, List<Log__c>> logsWithUsers = new Map<Id, List<Log__c>>();
        Map<Id, Set<Date>> logDatesWithUsers = new Map<Id, Set<Date>>();
        for(Log__c log : scope)
        {
            if(!logDatesWithUsers.containsKey(log.CreatedById)){
                //logsWithUsers.put(log.CreatedById, new List<Log__c>());
                logDatesWithUsers.put(log.CreatedById, new Set<Date>());
            }
                
            //logsWithUsers.get(log.CreatedById).add(log);
            logDatesWithUsers.get(log.CreatedById).add(log.Start_Date_Time__c.date());
        }
        Map<Id, User> usersWithId = new Map<Id, User>([Select Id, Name FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'Peeps Community User' OR Profile.Name = 'Peeps Community Manager' ]);

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailsToUsers = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        for(Id userId : usersWithId.keySet()){

            if(!logDatesWithUsers.containsKey(userId) || logDatesWithUsers.get(userId).size() < 5){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTargetObjectId(userId);
                mail.setSubject('Submit Time sheets for '+weekToSubmit+' asap');
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                String htmlMessage = 'Respected ' + usersWithId.get(userId).Name + ',<br><br>';

                String datesToSubmit = '';
                for(Date x = weekMondayDate; x < weekFridayDate || x.isSameDay(weekFridayDate); x = x.addDays(1)){
                    if(!logDatesWithUsers.containsKey(userId) || !logDatesWithUsers.get(userId)?.contains(x))
                        datesToSubmit += x.format() + ', ';
                }

                htmlMessage += 'This email is to request you to submit '+datesToSubmit+' timesheets asap,<br><br>';
                htmlMessage += '<br>';
                htmlMessage += 'Best regards,<br>';
                htmlMessage += 'HR';
    
                mail.setHtmlBody(htmlMessage);
    
                emailsToUsers.add(mail);
            }
            
        }
        
        if(!emailsToUsers.isEmpty()){
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.SendEmail(emailsToUsers);
            if (results[0].success) {
                System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
            } else {
                System.debug('The email failed to send: '
                    + results[0].errors[0].message);
            }
        }
            }


    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

- Test Class

```
@IsTest
private class WeekendTimeSheetAlertsTest {
    
    @IsTest
    static void testBatchExecution() {
        // Create test data
        Profile profile1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Peeps Community User' LIMIT 1];
        Contact contact = new Contact(FirstName = 'John', LastName = 'Doe', Email = 'john.doe@example.com');
        insert contact;
        
        UserRole role = new UserRole(Name = 'Test Role');
        insert role;
        
        User user;
        System.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId())) {
            user = new User(
                FirstName = 'User',
                LastName = 'One',
                Email = 'user1@example.com',
                UserName = 'TestManager2@example.com',
                Alias = 'test',
                CommunityNickname = 'test1',
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                ProfileId = profile1.Id,
                ContactId = contact.Id
            );
            insert user;
            
           // UserRole userRole = new UserRole(UserId = user.Id, RoleId = role.Id);
            //insert userRole;
        }
        
        List<Log__c> logs = new List<Log__c>();
        Date weekMondayDate = Date.today().toStartOfWeek();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            logs.add(new Log__c(
                Start_Date_Time__c = System.now().addDays(-7),
                End_Date_Time__c = System.now(),
                CreatedById = user.Id,
                CreatedBy = user,
                Status__c = 'Submit for Approval'
            ));
        }
        insert logs;
        
        // Start the batch
        Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new WeekendTimeSheetAlerts());
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Verify the email was sent
        List<EmailMessage> sentEmails = [
            SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlBody
            FROM EmailMessage
            WHERE ParentId = :user.Id
        ];
        
        System.assertEquals(0, sentEmails.size());
        // System.assertEquals('Submit Time sheets for THIS_WEEK asap', sentEmails[0].Subject);
    }
}
```

- Error

> ```
> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): UserRole, original object: Contact: []
> Class.WeekendTimeSheetAlertsTest.testBatchExecution: line 12, column 1
> ```

Answer (score 3):

As the error states, you can't directly insert a UserRole after creating a contact. Use System.runAs to get around this problem:

```
UserRole role role = new UserRole(Name = 'Test Role');
System.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId())) {
  insert role;
}
```

Comment: Getting the same error